# Cross-domain Ajax request with Spring MVC Rest API works with Safari only

Tags: jquery, rest, spring-mvc, safari, jackson

I have 2 different projects, where the web-application needs to access some Rest APIs on the server side. Therefore, I set up a Spring MVC Rest API with JacksonMapper on the server-side and JSONP requests with Jquery.ajax() on the client-side, which works fine.

However, I figured out that Safari (Version 6.0.5) displays the JSON response with GET requests and contenType "json" (on Rest API without a callback) perfectly, whereas all other browsers fail. Just for curiosity, can somebody explain how this is possible?

Here is the request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: url,
    data: {
        origin: start.toUrlValue(6),
        destination: dest.toUrlValue(6)
    },

    success: function (data) {          
        console.log(data);
        var res = JSON.stringify(data); //json to string
        $('#result').text(res);
    },

    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
    },
 });
```

**UPDATE**
To clearify the problem. The request gets to the API and I can see, that the server is doing the work and sending the JSON response. I'm just not able to process the response in any other browser.

Comment: look in your console at the error code and message for the failed GET request. what does it say?

Comment: there is not much there. it only says {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}

Comment: So, for all browsers, you're getting a 200 status code AND a json object in response?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its likely that there's anything wrong with the API.

Instead, what is very likely is that the functions you're using to *send the data to the API* is not supported across all browsers.

1. You may not always be getting a value for the `url` variable
2. You may not always have the `.toUrlValue` method

Using firebug in firefox, you can inspect the POST params that you're sending from the request. Make sure that your POST data is not different between the different browsers.

Comment: Thats actually a good idea. However, I even hardcoded the URL with parameters in the requests. On the server-side, I can see that the API gets called fine and it starts doing some job and sending back the response. I'm just not able to process the response with any other browser than Safari.

Comment: does your API have a Debug mode? if so, turn it on and inspect everything as it happens. also get familiar with writing to php logs if you haven't already. its like in JS when you write to the console.

Comment: Ya I'm using a Logger on the Spring Rest Api which shows that the response looks exactly the same no matter which browser the request came from. I think it must have something to do with cross-domain and probably some security differences between browsers?

Comment: if you're definitely getting the JSON response in all browsers, there is something going on within your callback function.